# How to use rotation css along with jQuery draggable ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I have a div tag which has:

```
id="ipad" style="background-image: url(images/large-ipad.png); -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 511px; height: 356px; padding: 41px 67px 41px 67px;
        margin: auto;"
```

and inside the div there is a span tag with

```
id="lbl1" style="-ms-transform:rotate(90deg)">
```

and some text between span tags

and javascript for it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {          
        $('#lbl1').draggable({
            containment: 'parent',
            scroll: false               
        });
    });
```

Basically what I want to do is I have a `div` tag which has ipad image in background. Now I have two option to rotate `div` tag 1.lanscape and 2.portrait. I achieved rotation of div tag by applying `css:-ms-transform:rotate(90deg)` to div tag but what happens after rotation is that the draggable does not work properly, it gets dragged outside the parent and even the text rotation doesnot work.

Can you help me out with this? Basically I want the draggable text to be rotated along with the div rotation and draggable should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

basically things doesn't go as this way,

you need to define a wide range of sizes as you except the users will browese your application
you must make use of the new css media query

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) { your css for this query goes here }
@media orientation (landscape or portrait){ ... }
```